# Disjoint bounding boxes

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Suppose I have a million triangles: How can I divide these triangles into 1000 groups (of arbitrary size), so that the 1000 minimal bounding boxes of these groups have as few pairwise overlaps as possible? A good heuristic will do.

Background information: I parallelize a geometric algorithm algorithm, where no two threads can work at the same place and the above groups shall be workunits with as few dependencies on each other as possible. My approach so far is to sort the triangles on a Hilbert curve and to create a new group every 1000 items. But of course this only takes into account the center of the bounding boxes, not their size.

Comment: How is the distribution of the triangles? Approximately uniform, or somewhat multimodal?

Comment: The triangles are located on the surface of a 3D object. Their size can vary greatly.

Comment: Oh, so do you have a complete triangulation of the surface, not just some triangles floating around unconnectedly?

Comment: Yes, that's the case.

Comment: What rules out having one bounding box for everything, and then 999 bounding boxes for individual triangles? There will be 999 overlaps, which is probably better than having 1000 boxes overlapping with multiple neighbors each.

Comment: That's true but the boxes are required for multithreading and it would not make sense to have one box containing almost all triangles because then one thread would receive all the work. I think about using an octree-like datastructure where I recursively subdivide the boxes into 8 octants while those boxes intersecting more than one octant would be sorted out and treated with the before mentioned Hilbert curve approach.